# Why DRF shows Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) without @api_view(['POST'])?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm learning react and try to make a login form using django-rest-framework(backend) and react(frontend). In react i created a login form ,when i submite the form it sends an axios.post to my view function. The problem is django raise a error and the message: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

**Obs1:If i include de @api_view(['POST']) decorator works, but i want to know if is possible make the request without it.**

**Obs2: When my react form render, a function that creates a csrf_token was called, so the csrf_token its being sent but django isn't reading it**

**Obs3: My django is in http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and my reactapp is in http://192.168.56.1:3000.**

When my Login render:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios({method:'get', url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/usuario/gera})
    .then(response=>{
        setToken(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error=>{})
},[])
```

When the form is submited:

```
function logar(e){
    document.cookie = `X-CSRFToken=${token}`
    login(email, senha1)
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

My axios(inside login function):

```
let token = getCookie('X-CSRFToken');

axios({
    method:'post', 
    url: url, 
    data:{email:email, password1:senha},
    headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': token},
    withCredentials: true
})
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(`Reposta: ${response.data}`)
})
.catch((error)=>{
    console.log(`Erro: ${error.data}`)
});
```

My django view:

```
def login_usuario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('Something')
```

My django settings:

```
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'X-CSRFTOKEN'

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'X-CSRFTOKEN',
    'csrftoken',
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    'content-type',
    'x-requested-with',
    'Authorization',
    'Set-Cookie'
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']

CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'http://192.168.56.1:3000' 

CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = 'http://localhost:3000'

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Comment: This is most often a problem on the client side. Are you sure `token` is correct? Go to the 'Network' tab in the Chrome developer tools (or equivalent in your browser of choice). This request should show up when you do this axios post. Check that the request has the proper `X-CSRFTOKEN` header.

Comment: Http headers are case insensitive. It should not matter if it's uppercase or not. But it is possible that Django is configured to use a different header name than the default "X-CSRFToken". https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_HEADER_NAME

Comment: Sry, my first question here. I will put more details!

Comment: It seems you have changed a lot of the default CSRF configurations in Django. Presumably you have some reason for each of those. Using different hosts for the django app and the javascript bundle makes reading the csrf token from the cookie harder, since the browser will block javascript from accessing some data. That's why Cross Site Request Forgery protection exists.

Comment: I make this changes because nothing workes kkkkk. I thought the different host were the problem, but i need someone telling me to be sure. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have not included the proper CSRF token in the axios http request.

Axios should be able to add the correct header and token if you tell it the header name and cookie name. These values should work if you use Django's default CSFR configuration.

```
axios({
    method:'post', 
    url: url, 
    data:{email:email, password1:senha},
    xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
    withCredentials: true
})
```

To make sure that Django has set the csrf token, you can use the `ensure_csrf_token` decorator on the view function that serves the page with your react app.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_token

@ensure_csrf_token
def react_app_view(request):
    return render(request, "react-app.html")
```

You can check that the cookie was set using the browser javascript console.

```
> document.cookie
'csrftoken=G2fjig7PImjIcvUFa6o39fTxwRcovp6Zh5iC5pkcmhBRETliwrZ2jt6bbcrvtpKa'
```